# switch back to previous view

Tags: motion-capture, blend-modes

I was looking at the normal screen. I wanted to import a .bvh file to put on my armature. I realized that I had not selected "MakeWalk > Load and Retarget" but I am in the *Import file* selection screen.
How do I get back to the previous screen so that I can select "MakeWalk > Load and Retarget"?

I tried everything in the upper far left Editor Type menu. Nothing
I tried <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd>. Nothing worked.

I restarted the program but I would prefer not having to do that if it can be avoided as it slows the speed of my work down.

(I also don't think this is a blend - mode question but it was the tag I found that came closest, please tell me what it is so I can tag it properly and make it easier for the next searcher)

---

**Edit:**

It looks like "Cancel" will do it. So instead of loading you cancel out.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can't go back.
You have to delete what it imported and re-import with the new settings.